# Getting grunt command not working

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

All the npm installs gave errors and warnings but would say "Everything is ok" at the end.
When I tried grunt serve, I got these warnings.

```
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-connect" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-watch" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-htmlmin" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-cssmin" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-uglify" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-bower-requirejs" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-eslint" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-jscs" not found. Is it installed?
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: "All the npm installs gave errors" - That might possibly be part of the reason for the Grunt warnings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you installing on a Mac or Windows? 
First, make sure the Grunt Client is installed within your directory:

```
$ npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Then:

```
$ npm install grunt-serve
```

Further documentation of installation can be found here:
https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-serve

Answer (score 1):

Try as below:

```
 1) npm install -g grunt-cli
```

This will put the grunt command in your system path, allowing it to be run from any directory.

Note that installing grunt-cli does not install the Grunt task runner! The job of the Grunt CLI is simple: run the version of Grunt which has been installed next to a Gruntfile. This allows multiple versions of Grunt to be installed on the same machine simultaneously.

```
 2) npm install grunt --save-dev 

 3) npm install grunt-serve
```

The easiest way to add Grunt and gruntplugins to an existing package.json is with the command npm install  --save-dev. Not only will this install  locally, but it will automatically be added to the devDependencies section, using a tilde version range.

for further assistance follow this link

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started